# Gerar arquivo csv no padrão Excel com CsvHelper C#

Tags: c#, .net, csv

Eu criei um projeto para gerar um arquivo .csv (que será usado no Excel). Até aqui está funcionando normalmente e esta sendo gerado no formato "Excel .csv", mas o problema é que ao abrir o arquivo (pelo Excel) o mesmo não está separado nas colunas como tabela.
Ficando tudo em uma coluna. Exemplo na imagem

**Acredito que o problema esteja no delimitador** pois se eu gerar um csv manualmente no Excel e ler por um editor de texto, as informações estarão separadas por **ponto e virgula** e não por **virgula** (que é como está ficando no meu caso).

Já tentei alterar o delimitador (onde o padrão está como ","), mas a propriedade não pode ser alterada (somente leitura).
Mas não tenho certeza se é isso. Ou se existe uma outra alternativa.

Segue abaixo parte do código que gera o arquivo, e a imagem do resultado final. Tentei deixar o máximo de informações possíveis para ajudar.

Versão do CsvHelper: 27.1.1

Classe:

```
public class DadosAnexo
{
        public string Matricula { get; set; }
        public string IdStc { get; set; }
        public string IdSip { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Método que gera o arquivo:

```
public void GerarArquivo()
    { 
        var nomePasta = "123456"; 
        var nomeArquivo = "Arquivo_123456.csv";
        var caminhoArquivo = @"C:\" + nomePasta; 
        
        if (!Directory.Exists(caminhoArquivo))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(caminhoArquivo);

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(caminhoArquivo, nomeArquivo)))
        using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            csvWriter.Context.RegisterClassMap<DadosAnexoMap>(); // mapeamento das coluna
            //csvWriter.Configuration.Delimiter = ";"; // aqui se rodar assim acontece um erro, pois essa propriedade não pode receber valor
            csvWriter.WriteRecords(GerarDadosAnexo());
            streamWriter.Flush();
        }

    }
```

Método que contem os dados:

```
public List<DadosAnexo> GerarDadosAnexo()
    {
        return new List<DadosAnexo>
        {
            new DadosAnexo
            {
                Matricula = "BC123456",
                IdStc = "Z123456",
                IdSip = "123456",
                Nome = "Marcos",
                Status = "ATIVO",
                CodOrigem = "123"
            },
            new DadosAnexo
            {
                Matricula = "BC123456",
                IdStc = "Z123456",
                IdSip = "123456",
                Nome = "Pedro",
                Status = "ATIVO",
                CodOrigem = "123"
            },
            new DadosAnexo
            {
                Matricula = "BC123456",
                IdStc = "Z123456",
                IdSip = "123456",
                Nome = "Amanda",
                Status = "ATIVO",
                CodOrigem = "123"
            }
        };
    }
```

Classe de mapeamento:

```
public class DadosAnexoMap : ClassMap<DadosAnexo>
{
    public DadosAnexoMap()
    {
         Map(m => m.Matricula).Name("MATRICULA");
         Map(m => m.IdStc).Name("ID STC");
         Map(m => m.IdSip).Name("ID SIP");
         Map(m => m.Nome).Name("NOME");
        Map(m => m.Status).Name("STATUS");
    }
}
```

Resultado (arquivo csv aberto pelo Excel), percebam que os dados não separaram:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Na verdade o arquivo está sendo gerado correto, o excel que não está abrindo como uma planilha separado por virgula. Já no Google Sheet abriu certo...

Comment: Verificou se você está utilizando a versão mais atual da biblioteca? A identificação da `,` ou do `;` como separador de listas também é uma configuração presente nas definições do idioma configurado na máquina.

Comment: @novic, pelo Excel direto não abri como precisa.

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, estou utilizando a ultima versão da biblioteca (27.1.1). E o idioma da maquina esta o padrão português ABNT2.

Comment: Não abre mesmo! eu relatei o problema para você, mas, não é o arquivo que está com problema é o excel que trabalha assim...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei a solução. Se tratava da região ao estanciar a classe **CsvWriter**. Onde é necessário informar como parâmetro. E o **CultureInfo** passsar a linguagem "pt-BR" como parâmetro.

Onde em vez de ser assim:

```
var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Fica assim:

```
var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(streamWriter, new CultureInfo("pt-BR", true));
```

Dessa forma ao escrever o csv, ele separa por ";" que é o padrão do Excel ao ler um arquivo csv no idioma pt-BR.